# Iterate over list of objects

Tags: java, jstl

Code in my controller is like

```
List<List<FormFieldsDO>> formFieldList=new ArrayList<List<FormFieldsDO>>();
    for(int i = 0 ;i< partialReportDO.getWorkFlowList().size(); i++ ){
        List<FormFieldsDO> listOfFormField =  formServices.getFieldListByWorkFlowId(partialReportDO.getWorkFlowList().get(i),
                        partialReportDO.getFieldIds());
        formFieldList.add(listOfFormField);
    }
    for (List<FormFieldsDO> list : formFieldList) {
        for (FormFieldsDO formFieldsDO : list) {

            map.addAttribute("formFieldList", formFieldsDO);
        }
    }
```

I just want to iterate `formFieldList` using JSTL code. I use to iterate above list is like

```
<c:forEach var="innerList" items="${formFieldList}">
   <c:forEach var="list" items="${innerList}">
    <th title="${list.title }">${list.title }</th>
</c:forEach>
```

but by using above code I'm getting exception. Don't know how to iterate over supplied `items` in `<forEach>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller code like this :

```
List<List<FormFieldsDO>> formFieldList=new ArrayList<List<FormFieldsDO>>();
for(int i = 0 ;i< partialReportDO.getWorkFlowList().size(); i++ ){
    List<FormFieldsDO> listOfFormField =  formServices.getFieldListByWorkFlowId(partialReportDO.getWorkFlowList().get(i),
                        partialReportDO.getFieldIds());
    formFieldList.add(listOfFormField);
}

map.addAttribute("formFieldList", formFieldList);
```

AND JSP code like this :

```
<c:forEach var="innerList" items="${formFieldList}">
   <c:forEach var="list" items="${innerList}">
      <th title="${list.title }">${list.title }</th>
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: You are always welcome. Do upvote using up arrow near the answer!